# Problemas con Conexion pdo y consultas preparadas php poo

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo

Me sale el siguiente error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\EPWeb\Admin\Negocios\CapaNegocios.php:17 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\EPWeb\Admin\Presentacion\Unidades.php(18):
>   Unidad->InsertarUnidad(1, 'z', 'a', 'a', 1) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\EPWeb\Admin\Negocios\CapaNegocios.php on line 17

Estoy aprendiendo, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
class Conexion{

    protected $conexion_db;

    public function Conectar()
    {
        try{

            $this->conexion_db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bd_espamep','root','123456');
            $this->conexion_db-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conexion_db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"):

                return $this->conexion_db;





        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "La linea de error es: " . $e->getline();
        }
    }
    public function desconectar()
    {
        $this -> conexion = null;
    }
}
?>

Negocios

<?php
require_once "../Conexion/CapaDatos.php";

class Unidad extends Conexion
{

    public function CapaNegocios()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function InsertarUnidad($idempresa, $uni_nombre, $uni_objetivo, $uni_logo, $uni_eliminado)
    {
        try
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO unidad(idempresa, uni_nombre, uni_objetivo, uni_logo, uni_eliminado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            $sentencia = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);
            $sentencia -> bind_param('isssi',$uni_nombre,$uni_objetivo, $uni_logo);

            $sentencia->execute();

            echo "Guardado";

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }



}

?>
```

Presentacion

```
<?php
require_once "../negocios/CapaNegocios.php";


try{
  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
    $idempresa = 1;
    $uni_eliminado = 1;
    $uni_nombre = $_POST['txtunidad'];
    $uni_objetivo = $_POST['txtobjetivou'];
    $uni_logo = $_POST['logou'];

    $objetoNegocio= new Unidad();

    if(isset($_POST["Guardar"]))
    {
      $objetoNegocio-> InsertarUnidad($idempresa, $uni_nombre, $uni_objetivo, $uni_logo, $uni_eliminado);
    }
  }
}
catch(PD0Eception $e)
{
  echo $e -> getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola Tevin, el código parece que tiene algunos problemas (o falta añadir algo a la pregunta). Por ejemplo: la conexión se abre en el método `Conectar` que no se llama en ningún sitio (lo que haría que conexion_db sea null, que es el error que recibes). Aparte en la inserción tienes 5 parámetros pero en el bind sólo le pasas 3, eso debería darte otro error más adelante. No sé si esos problemas son porque no has agregado todo el código o porque realmente son el problema que quieres resolver.

Comment: Si lo de los parametros se me paso por alto por lo que he estado probando y cambiando, Estoy aprendiendo, me podrías especificar como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Hacer el qué? ¿resolviste ya el problema de la pregunta?

Comment: Llamada al metodo conectar

Comment: Pon la llamada en el constructor. Un segundo, te lo pongo como respuesta para que sea más fácil verlo.

Comment: Ok, gracias me ayudaría mucho

Answer (score 0):

La clase `Conexion` tiene un método para conectarse a la base de datos (`Conectar`) pero ese método no se llama en ninguna parte. Una cosa que puedes hacer es crear un constructor por defecto que llame al método `Conectar` para que de ese modo el atributo `$conexion_db` tenga un valor.

```
<?php
class Conexion{

    protected $conexion_db;

    public function Conectar()
    {
        try{

            $this->conexion_db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bd_espamep','root','123456');
            $this->conexion_db-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conexion_db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"):

            return $this->conexion_db;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "La linea de error es: " . $e->getline();
        }
    }
    public function desconectar()
    {
        $this -> conexion = null;
    }

    // constructor por defecto que crea la conexión
    function __construct() {
        $this -> Conectar();
    }
}
?>
```

Además, en la clase `Unidad` no se está llamando al constructor del padre porque tampoco tiene un constructor por defecto. Tiene un método `CapaNegocios()` que llama la constructor del padre... pero que no se llama desde ninguna parte. Añádele algo como esto:

y entonces quedaría así:

```
class Unidad extends Conexion
{

    public function CapaNegocios()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function InsertarUnidad($idempresa, $uni_nombre, $uni_objetivo, $uni_logo, $uni_eliminado)
    {
        try
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO unidad(idempresa, uni_nombre, uni_objetivo, uni_logo, uni_eliminado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            $sentencia = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

            // corregido con datos de los comentarios y la ayuda de A.Cedano
            $arrParams=array($idempresa, $uni_nombre, $uni_objetivo, $uni_logo, $uni_eliminado); 
            $sentencia->execute($arrParams);

            echo "Guardado";

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // constructor por defecto que llama al padre
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    } 

}
```

Prueba eso y entonces `$conexion_db` ya debería tener un valor. Dime si sigue dándote el error.

Comment: Ahora no solo me sale el mismo error, tambien sale que hay un fallo en la linea 16 de la capa datos: $this->conexion_db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bd_espamep','root','123456');

Comment: AHORA ME SALE ESTO:                                                                              Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\EPWeb\Admin\Negocios\CapaNegocios.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\EPWeb\Admin\Presentacion\Unidades.php(18): Unidad->InsertarUnidad(1, 'a', 'a', 'a', 1) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\EPWeb\Admin\Negocios\CapaNegocios.php on line 18

Comment: La linea 18 es esta: $sentencia -> bind_param('isssi', $idempresa, $uni_nombre, $uni_objetivo, $uni_logo, $uni_eliminado);
el ultimo valor lo tengo contemplado como bit en la db, no se si eso debe ser el problema

Comment: @TevinLectong el error que te sale ahora es porque la función PDO es [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) y no `bind_param`. Lo he corregido en el código de arriba.

Comment: Alvaro `bindParam` (PDO)  no funciona como `bind_param` (mysqli). En PDO esto es incorrecto: `$sentencia -> bindParam('isssi', $idempresa, $uni_nombre, $uni_objetivo, $uni_logo, $uni_eliminado);` pues esa forma es propia de mysqli... Tienes que hacer el binding uno por uno, o bien meter sólo las variables en un array y pasar ese array en el `execute`. Algo así: `$arrParams=array($idempresa, $uni_nombre, $uni_objetivo, $uni_logo, $uni_eliminado);  $sentencia->execute($arrParams);` And... that's all!

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón, voy a corregir eso en el código.